# AMD hardware design specifics: why slower at "numerical" tasks?

Tags: cpu

I was hoping to ask this question in a way that doesn't get me downvoted or labelled as a troll!

I have an imac i7, and a home built pc with a phenom II X4 @ 3.4 Ghz (both with about the same amount of ram). This was a deliberate plan - as I didn't want to pay the extra for intel. I have bought another box set of some dvds and was transcoding them down to ipad format so that I could watch on the train. the Imac is about three times as fast when using the same handbrake profile (as per Frames per second)

As a geek though - I was wondering if anyone could shed any technical specifics on why AMD is slower at 'raw number crunching' type tasks. I have read quite a bit on the internet about it but still haven't really found a succinct explanation. The best that I've gotten to is that AMD have lots of smaller ("narrower") in the processor, where intel has a big, wide, 'superhighway'

I get that intel has a bigger budget, but for as long as I can remember, AMD has been the cost-conscious choice that has lagged behind when it comes to raw number crunching, I guess I'm slightly surprised that they haven't caught up.

Again, this is not a complaint, a moan or a dig, I'm just curious about the specifics.

-ace

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise, but I'm willing to bet in this case that the i7 is using some proprietary code paths or extensions that make it way faster *at these particular kinds of operations*.  I know apparently QuickSync is amazingly optimized for transcoding.  It doesn't mean they're ALWAYS that far apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the specifics on the processor in your iMac, it's hard to get specific.  But... you need to remember that a hyperthreaded processor is like a dual core processor.  Not *exactly* the same, but similar.  Hear me out.

A P4 HT 3.3ghz processor can perform better than a single core 3.3ghz processor where multi-tasking is concerned.  Raw number crunching is one of those things where if the Operating system AND the software in question will utilize multi-cores properly, a 4 core HT processor will outperform a 4 core non HT processor.

So... you've got an i7, which is probably at the LEAST a 4 core/8 thread processor, and you are comparing it to a 4 core processor.  Well... that's almost like comparing an 8 core processor to a 4 core processor.  Again, not exactly like comparing, but almost like comparing.

Here's a [Passmark benchmark](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD%20Phenom%20II%20X4%20965) for that Phenom compared to some other processors.  Note, the performance graphs are first, and rating for the $$$$ value is second.  As you note, Intel will outperform AMD, but AMD will make a budget before it breaks it.

Comment: interesting - so my intel most likely is behaving like an 8 core machine, but my AMD like the 4 core it purports to be - all because of hyperthreading?

Comment: All 1st and 2nd generation Core i7 processors are at *least* 4 core/8 thread processors http://ark.intel.com/ the highest end of the series are 6 core/12 thread.  So, in essence, yes.  It is behaving like an 8 core machine.